# UIAlertController title and message not appearing

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default AlertController", message: "A standard alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
    print("you have pressed the Cancel button");
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
    print("you have pressed OK button");
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is is what the code around the presentation looks like. I am checking the auth status of CloudKit and then presenting an alert if there is an error:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

    guard let user = user where succeeded && error == nil else {
        if let error = error {
            switch error {
            default:

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default AlertController", message: "A standard alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                    print("you have pressed the Cancel button");
                }
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

                let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                    print("you have pressed OK button");
                }
                alertController.addAction(OKAction)

                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
            }
        }
        return
    }
})
```

Comment: From where and when you are calling the alert showing method ?

Comment: In an async method, but I use `dispatch_async` to get the main queue

Comment: Also, it's in a storyboard

Comment: Can you add that code too ? I suspect the issue is related to showing the alert from background thread or something similar.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your alert.  I made a new project, slapped down a button, and made the button run your code verbatim.  It works, and I see the title and body.  Clearly something external is messing with you.  If you go to Debug -> View Debugging -> Show View Frames, do you see frames for where the title and body should be?  Is it possible the text is white for some crazy reason?

Comment: Please upload a sample project which reproduces the error.  The code you have provided does not reproduce this issue.