# UIAlertView and UIAlertController title does not display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have created an alert as follows :

```
// UIAlertView
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WARNING" message:@"Are you sure you want to quit ?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Confirm" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[alertView show];

// or UIAlertController
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING" message:@"Are you sure you want to quit ?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:NULL]];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:NULL]];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But both the effects are like this : [image]

I try to log the title of alert, but the result is null : [image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Before you try to fix if for `UIAlertView`: Don't use it. It's deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: Are you using setTitle somewhere in your code ?

Comment: goto Product -> clean and try again

Comment: there is something external is missing with your project, your code looks perfect i included your `alertcontroller` code in my project it works fine. Just try once cleaning build folder by press together `shift+command+option+k` or go with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621525/uialertcontroller-title-and-message-not-appearing) may helps.

Comment: @vishnuvarthan I check all the files of my project, there is no such method of UIAlertView or UIAlertController.

Comment: @SathiReddy I did it many times, but I still didn't fix it.

Comment: @vaibhav I clean build folder, but it still don't work .

Comment: @Steven.L just share your project using github or something else if you can so we rectify you problem if..

Answer (score 0):

Both of them is work in my side.

Try to use this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WARNING" message:@"Are you sure you want to quit ?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Confirm" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [alertView show];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(grHandler)]];
}

-(void)grHandler{
    // UIAlertController
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING" message:@"Are you sure you want to quit ?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:NULL]];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:NULL]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Comment: I create a new project (for iOS7 and later), the code is work, but it do not work in the project of the company.